# Running shell scripts from Vtune Amplifier

Tags: optimization, avx2, intel-vtune

I am new to VTune and trying to profile an application. I want to call the executable using a shell script as there are many parameters and quite long too.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Intel VTune (total majority of application analysis type) and in Intel Advisor (survey, roofline, tripcounts) you just specify the name of your script as "target executable" (where you normally specify your ".exe" file name) and that is it. Should be simple.

By default Intel profilers will follow the tree of processes created by script down to your real application.

*Side note:* With Intel Inspector and some very advanced parts of Intel Advisor (MAP and Dependencies) you might need to specify "Child Application", because they do not follow whole tree of processes by default, as it is too expensive.

Comment: Additionally, when you use shell script as an executable, make sure "Analyze child processes" option is turned on in "Advanced" section of "What" pane in the "Configure Analysis" dialog. It is checked on by default.